# Finding the super-mean (NOT the mean) of a set of numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

the super-mean is found by grouping pairs of numbers and finding the average successively
until there is just one number. For example,

$$(1-2-3-4-5) \to ((1+2)/2,(2+3)/2,(3+4)/2,(4+5)/2) \\ 
(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5) \to(1.5+2.5)/2,(2.5+3.5)/2,(3.5+4.5)/2) \\
(2.0,3.0,4.0) \to2.5,2.5)$$

Then the super-mean is 3.0.i suspect a relationship between these problems and pascal triangles, then binomial coefficients, how to find the super-mean out of the set of numbers. I have read that the super-mean is given by:

$$S_{n} = \left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}\binom{n - 1}{i}a_{i}$$

$n$ is the size of the input $[0, \ldots, n]$.
$(1,2,3,4,5) \to n = 4$

How can I relate the problem with this formula, how do i derive the formula for the super-mean.?. Is there any reading material for these kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supermean is a mean of the number with coefficients.

To find out the coefficient $p_k^n$ of the $k^{th}$ item of a sequence $a_0\dots a_n$, it suffices to see that this number contributes in two ways in the next step (except for $a_0$ and $a_n$ which are on the sides).

Therefore we have the induction formula:
$$p_k^n=p_{k-1}^{n-1}+p_{k}^{n-1}$$ with the base cases $p_{-1}^n=p_{n+1}^n=0$ and $p_0^n=p_n^n=1$ for all $n$.

This means we get exactly the  induction formula for the binomial coefficients, and indeed your formula for $S_n$ is good.